# Make description div dynamical populated on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently there are 3 image divs and three description divs, where image previews are shown. With a click on `col-md-4 product-quickview` the image preview is shown in the description div.

I don't wan't to have 3 images descriptions divs in my HTML, because I only wan't to show one image at the time. I wan't one dynamically populated by jQuery code

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drzo0uez/)

```
$('.descriptions .panel').hide();
$('#grid .product-quickview').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).parents('.col-md-3').index();
    var row = $(this).parents('.col-md-3').parent().next('.row');
    $('#grid img').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
    //$('.descriptions .panel').hide();
    row.find('.descriptions .panel').eq(idx).toggle("slow","swing");
});
```

So the effect I'm trying to achieve is to remove the 3 hard coded description divs and replace them with one dynamically populated div, based on image preview click.

If you need any additional information please let me know and I will provide.

Comment: uncomment: //$('.descriptions .panel').hide(); it is the fastest solution. dynamic description, of course, a better solution.

Comment: Yeah your `$('.descriptions .panel').hide();` works, why would you comment it?

Comment: Yes this is fastest solution, but i wan't to level up this thingy. So let's say somebody already previewed image, when user clicks on another preview i wan't just description content to change. And i also need to change this toggle function with show or hide, so clicking preview on the already previewed image, should close the preview div, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be super clear on the functionality you're looking for.
This version only has one area for your currently viewed image / desc. It opens the first time only, then just changes based on clicks. The image description is in a data tag `data-desc` on the clicked image.

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drzo0uez/10/)

Comment: mm i like it. Is it possible to make also to work this way: 1. User clicks on preview image. 2 Images gets previewed 3. users clicks on SAME image preview again 4. description closes

Comment: Sure, I've updated it again. This identifies it by the image src. So if the image src of the currently open image is the same, it will close it.

Comment: there is one more trouble. Image is previewed and you click on other image preview. Description gets closed. This should automatically open next image preview

Comment: That's because it's the same image src. If you put a different image src, it will just update instead of closing.

Comment: oh sorry :D my bad. Thank you for this. It was bugging me for some time.
you are the men! ;)

Comment: I've updated again so that it checks for both the image src and the description, that way you can have multiple images from the same src. Ideally, you'd probably want to set some product id somewhere in a `data-productid` tag and base everything off that, but I'm working within the frame of what you gave.